# Export Sharepoint 2007 Custom List as RSS File

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Here's our scenario:

1. We've created a sharepoint 2007 calendar on our intranet site

   We want to run a daily job to export a subset of the events to an rss file

   Another job will move the rss file to our public web site

We have some funny restrictions where we can't simply publish the rss feed to the public. We have to go this export route.

I'm not clear on how to accomplish step 2. Ideally, we wouldn't have to write a lot of custom code to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is - Use SQL Server Integration Services with the [SharePoint List Source and Destination widget from CodePlex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365137.aspx)

Hope this helps someone else out there.